# Composition of an integer

Tags: combinatorics

Show that there exist $2^{n-1}-1$ ways of representing a natural number $n$ by a sum considering the order of the summands. ($\mathbb{N}$ is defined without zero)

Example:

Let be $n=7$ then we have $1+6=7$ and $6+1=7$. So $\{1,6\}$ and $\{6, 1\}$ count as two representations of $n$.

Does someone have a tip of how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What about number $4$? All the representations are $$4=1+1+1+1\\4=2+1+1\\4=2+2\\4=3+1\\4=4$$which are $5$ not $2^{4-1}-1=7$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My apologies, I had copied the exercise wrong. One has to take the order into consideration. I have already edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), although, in this case, the author apparently wishes to express $n$ as the sum of two or more positive integers.

Consider the case $n = 7$.  We can express $7$ as a list of seven ones, with six spaces between them.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
By placing either a comma or an addition sign between each pair of ones, we can express $7$ as a sum of a sequence of positive integers.  For instance, if we write
$$1, 1, 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1$$
we obtain $7 = 3 + 1 + 2 + 1$.  Since there are two choices for each entry, there are $2^6$ ways to express $7$ as an ordered sum of one or more positive integers, of which $2^6 - 1$ express $7$ as an ordered sum of two or more positive integers.

In general, we can express $n$ as an ordered sum of one or more positive integers in $2^{n - 1}$ ways, of which $2^{n - 1} - 1$ involve at least two summands.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N_n$ be the number of ways to express $n$ as itself or as a sum of positive integers.
i.e. $N_n - 1$ is the number you want.

Let's say $a_1 + \ldots + a_m = n$, then either

1. $m = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$
2. or $m > 1$ and $1 \le a_m \le n-1$.
   For a given $a_m$, there are $N_{n-a_m}$ ways to pick $(a_1, \ldots, a_{m-1})$.

This leads to following recurrence relation on $N_n$,

$$N_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}N_k\quad\text{ for } n > 1$$

The statement is clearly also true for $n = 1$. Now substitute $n$ by $n+1$, one can deduce

$$N_{n+1} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}N_k = \left( 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} N_k \right) + N_n = N_n + N_n = 2N_n$$

Since $N_1 = 1$, this leads to $N_n = 2^{n-1}$ and hence the number of expressing $N$ as a sum of two or more positive integers is $N_n - 1 = 2^{n-1} - 1$.